# Remove wide empty spaces between rows in a longtable environment

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, longtable, multirow, vertical-spacing

I need to reduce the spacing between the two rows as indicated by the arrows in the figure. I tried complying with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % used for rotating and adjusting text
%\usepackage{tabularx}% automatically calculates the widths of certain columns depending on total width of the table.
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx}
\LTcapwidth=7in
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}

{\small\tabcolsep=2.0pt
    \begin{longtable}{>{\centering}p{2.4cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{3.5cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1.5cm}>{\centering}p{0.7cm}>{\centering}p{2cm}>{\centering}p{1.5cm}>{\centering}p{2.6cm}p{2.4cm}}
        \caption{Applications of MMCs in various domains based on the design drivers.}\vspace*{-1.5mm} \\
        \toprule[0.25mm]
        \label{tab:tab_4}
        \multirow{3}{*}{Matrix}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Reinforcement} & \multirow{3}{*}{Fabrication procedure} &\multicolumn{6}{c}{Mechanical properties}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{Year/Ref.}}\bigstrut\\ \cline{2-4} \cline{6-11}
        &\multirow{2}{*}{State}&\multirow{2}{*}{Vol\%}&\multirow{2}{*}{Wt\%}&&\multirow{1}{*}{TS}&\multirow{1}{*}{YS}&\multirow{1}{*}{$\delta$\%}&\multirow{1}{*}{H}&\multirow{1}{*}{E}&Other Properties/&\bigstrut \\ 
        &&&&&(Mpa)&(Mpa)&&(Hv/Gpa)&(Gpa)&interface&\\ \midrule[0.25mm]
        \endfirsthead  \toprule
        \multirow{3}{*}{Matrix}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Reinforcement} & \multirow{3}{*}{Fabrication procedure} &\multicolumn{6}{c}{Mechanical properties}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{Year/Ref.}}\bigstrut\\ \cline{2-4} \cline{6-11}
        &\multirow{2}{*}{State}&\multirow{2}{*}{Vol\%}&\multirow{2}{*}{Wt\%}&&\multirow{1}{*}{TS}&\multirow{1}{*}{YS}&\multirow{1}{*}{$\delta$\%}&\multirow{1}{*}{H}&\multirow{1}{*}{E}&Other Properties/&\bigstrut \\ 
        &&&&&(Mpa)&(Mpa)&&(Hv/Gpa)&(Gpa)&interface&  \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
        \endhead
        Al 5083 alloy powder & GNP & --& 0 & \multirow{1}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{BM\footnote{Ball Milling}+ compaction + sintering + extrusion}} & 219 & 301 & 6.6& --& -- & --& XXXXXX$^{183}$  \\ 
        &&--&0.5&&287&434&4.6&--&--&--&\\ 
        &&--&1&&332&470&3&--&--&--&\bigstrut \\ 
        Pristine Al (99.5\%)&rGO&--&0&\multirow{1}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{Preparation of Al and rGO dispersants + Ultrasonicated + filtering + drying + CC + sintering.}}&--&--&--&26$\pm$1.3 HV&--&--& XXXXXX $^{217}$\\    
        &&--&0.07&&--&--&--&29$\pm$1.9 HV&--&--&\\            
        &&--&0.15&&--&--&--&30.2$\pm$2 HV&--&--&\\  
        &&--&0.13&&--&--&--&34.5$\pm$3 HV&--&--& \bigstrut\\          
        AlMg5 (99.5\%) &GO&0\%&--&\multirow{1}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{BM + HIP \footnote{Hot isostatic pressing}}}&260&130&25&70$\pm$2.3Hv&53 ind.\footnote{indentation modulus}&Flexural: 210&XXXXXX$^{182}$ \\  
        &&1\%&--&&556&200&10&166$\pm$2.3 Hv&73 ind.&&\\  
        Al 7055 powder + GO ( 1, 3, 5 @ wt\%)&GO&--&0&\multirow{1}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{Mixture was wet blended + vacuum dried + SPS \footnote{Spark Plasma Sintering}}}&--&$\sim$570&--&131.5 Hv&--&--&XXXXXXX$^{205}$\\    
        &&&1&&--&$\sim$410&--&151.2 Hv&--&--&\\
        &&&3&&--&$\sim$300&--&128.3 Hv&--&--&\\
        &&&5&&--&$\sim$250&--&98.6 Hv&--&--&\\

        
        
    \end{longtable} 
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output is as follows:]

Comment: Substitute `Al 5083 alloy powder` with `\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2cm}{\centering Al 5083 alloy powder}}`. The same for `Pristine Al (99.5\%)` and `Al 7055 powder + GO ( 1, 3, 5 @ wt\%)`

Answer (score 2):

[image: xr]

This is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % used for rotating and adjusting text
%\usepackage{tabularx}% automatically calculates the widths of certain columns depending on total width of the table.
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx}
\LTcapwidth=7in
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

{\small\tabcolsep=2.0pt
    \begin{longtable}{>{\centering}p{2.4cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{3.5cm}>{\centering}p{1cm}>{\centering}p{1.5cm}>{\centering}p{0.7cm}>{\centering}p{2cm}>{\centering}p{1.5cm}>{\centering}p{2.6cm}p{2.4cm}}
        \caption{Applications of MMCs in various domains based on the design drivers.}\vspace*{-1.5mm} \\
        \toprule[0.25mm]
        \label{tab:tab_4}
        \multirow{3}{*}{Matrix}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Reinforcement} & \multirow{3}{*}{Fabrication procedure} &\multicolumn{6}{c}{Mechanical properties}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{Year/Ref.}}\bigstrut\\ \cline{2-4} \cline{6-11}
        &\multirow{2}{*}{State}&\multirow{2}{*}{Vol\%}&\multirow{2}{*}{Wt\%}&&\multirow{1}{*}{TS}&\multirow{1}{*}{YS}&\multirow{1}{*}{$\delta$\%}&\multirow{1}{*}{H}&\multirow{1}{*}{E}&Other Properties/&\bigstrut \\ 
        &&&&&(Mpa)&(Mpa)&&(Hv/Gpa)&(Gpa)&interface&\\ \midrule[0.25mm]
        \endfirsthead  \toprule
        \multirow{3}{*}{Matrix}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Reinforcement} & \multirow{3}{*}{Fabrication procedure} &\multicolumn{6}{c}{Mechanical properties}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{Year/Ref.}}\bigstrut\\ \cline{2-4} \cline{6-11}
        &\multirow{2}{*}{State}&\multirow{2}{*}{Vol\%}&\multirow{2}{*}{Wt\%}&&\multirow{1}{*}{TS}&\multirow{1}{*}{YS}&\multirow{1}{*}{$\delta$\%}&\multirow{1}{*}{H}&\multirow{1}{*}{E}&Other Properties/&\bigstrut \\ 
        &&&&&(Mpa)&(Mpa)&&(Hv/Gpa)&(Gpa)&interface&  \\ \midrule[0.25mm]
        \endhead
       \multirow{1}[3]{2.4cm}{\centering Al 5083 alloy powder} & GNP & --& 0 & \multirow{1}[3]{3cm}{BM\footnote{Ball Milling}+ compaction + sintering + extrusion} & 219 & 301 & 6.6& --& -- & --& XXXXXX$^{183}$  \\ 
        &&--&0.5&&287&434&4.6&--&--&--&\\ 
        &&--&1&&332&470&3&--&--&--& \bigstrut\\ 
       \multirow{1}[5]{2.4cm}{\centering Pristine Al (99.5\%)}&rGO&--&0& \multirow{1}[5]{3cm}{Preparation of Al and rGO dispersants + Ultrasonicated + filtering + drying + CC + sintering.}&--&--&--&26$\pm$1.3 HV&--&--& XXXXXX $^{217}$\\    
        &&--&0.07&&--&--&--&29$\pm$1.9 HV&--&--&\\            
        &&--&0.15&&--&--&--&30.2$\pm$2 HV&--&--&\\  
        &&--&0.13&&--&--&--&34.5$\pm$3 HV&--&--& \bigstrut \\[10pt]  % <<<<<<<      
        AlMg5 (99.5\%) &GO&0\%&--&\multirow{1}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{BM + HIP \footnote{Hot isostatic pressing}}}&260&130&25&70$\pm$2.3Hv&53 ind.\footnote{indentation modulus}&Flexural: 210&XXXXXX$^{182}$ \\  
        &&1\%&--&&556&200&10&166$\pm$2.3 Hv&73 ind.&& \bigstrut\\  
       Al 7055 powder&GO&--&0& \multirow{1}[4]{3cm}{Mixture was wet blended + vacuum dried + SPS \footnote{Spark Plasma Sintering}}&--&$\sim$570&--&131.5 Hv&--&--&XXXXXXX$^{205}$\\    
        &&--&1&&--&$\sim$410&--&151.2 Hv&--&--&\\
        &&--&3&&--&$\sim$300&--&128.3 Hv&--&--&\\
        &&--&5&&--&$\sim$250&--&98.6 Hv&--&--&\\
        
        
    \end{longtable} 
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

`\multirow{1}[3]{3cm}{BM\footnote{Ball Milling}+ compaction + sintering + extrusion}`

`{1}` makes the multirow start in the first line of `[3]` lines with a width of `{3cm}`. Text will be left align.

The same should be applied to the fist column of the row, thus eliminating the extra line, as you wanted.

Row # 7 needs to be "expanded" by `[10pt]` because the `multirow` needs 5 rows but only 4 rows are available to fit the text.

To improve the readability of the table  you should consider separate the blocks by  adding more space in between, using `\\[10pt]` instead of `\bigstrut\\` after each block.

[image: xxx]

Comment: Got it, Thank you !!!